# Appending form data after clicking submit

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a form that returns data that is specified with an ID but every when I click the submit button after having previously done a submit it appends the new results to the bottom of the previous one. Is there a way to get the new results onto a different page or refresh the page with the new result?

Here is my code.

```html
<form method = "post" target = "_blank">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="id">ID</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idtext"            aria-describedby="idHelp" placeholder="Enter ID">
          <small id="idHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter ID number</small>
        </div>
        <div>
        <button type="button" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div id="idOutput"> </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: The button in your code snippet doesn't currently run any script.

Answer (score 0):

define action of your form. to the page you want to send the data, data will be available on the field name basis not on the ID, if you want data to change the data value or key value pair, then use ajax.

hope this may help.